# Set locale to system default UTF-8

Tags: r, utf-8, locale, rapache

When running R inside rApache, the locale is inherited from the Apache webserver, and therefore `Sys.getlocale()` is always equal to `"C"`. I would like my web application to use `UTF8`, so I use:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

However this doesn't work on machines that do not have this locale available:

```
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using “C”
```

Is there any way to use `Sys.setlocale` to set the locale to the system default `UTF-8`? I.e. something that would also work on Windows or a German Linux?

Comment: Have you considered setting the encoding to 'UTF-8' on any reads from the "outside"?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I was misremembering something I read earlier this week on rdev. Perhaps one of these will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387910/losing-locale-when-running-fcgi-script  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985201/encoding-is-not-proper-when-query-from-apache-php/18079287#18079287   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674519/why-php-developers-cant-provide-setlocale-function-as-per-thread-scope

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question: On Ubuntu the default `LANG` is defined in `/etc/default/locale`:

```
jeroen@dev:~⟫ cat /etc/default/locale
# Created by cloud-init v. 0.7.7 on Wed, 29 Jun 2016 11:02:51 +0000
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

So in R we could do something like:

```
readRenviron("/etc/default/locale")
LANG <- Sys.getenv("LANG")
if(nchar(LANG))
   Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", LANG)
```

Apache also has a line in `/etc/apache2/envvars` that can be uncommented to enable this.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed solved the issue with RApache when sending text to the webservice in UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "English_United States.1252")
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I tested it only on Windows 7, 64 bit. I am not sure about linux versions, but I remember once I had this issue on ubuntu, and I followed the instructions on this link to change my locale settings. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue. Please do not quote me for linux versions, because I am not sure.

Comment: I just tested this on my ubuntu machine. I followed the link in my previous comment. Then, I opened a fresh "R" session. The locale settings were automatically changed to en_US.UTF8. If you want to revert back to "C" locale type  or "POSIX" type, use the function: Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "C"). HTH

Comment: This does not actually set the locale to UTF-8. This setting is latin1.

Comment: On my case, i solved my encoding issues by using the same line but setting ``"en_US.UTF-8"`` as locale. Many thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to make a check for the OS. The locale names differ by OS, see the examples at the help file.

```
?Sys.getlocale()

Examples

Sys.getlocale()
Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
## Not run: 
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de")     # Solaris: details are OS-dependent
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.utf8")   # Modern Linux etc.
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE.UTF-8")  # ditto
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")  # OS X, in UTF-8
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "German") # Windows

## End(Not run)
Sys.getlocale("LC_PAPER")          # may or may not be set

## Not run: 
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")   # turn off locale-specific sorting,
                                   # usually, but not on all platforms
## End(Not run)
```