# Encoding of CSV file from Excel (Mac) when reading it into R

Tags: r, excel, csv, encoding

I have an Excel file with some text. I have saved it as CSV file and read into R using `readr::read_csv2()`. But I cannot figure out how to get rid of the weird characters below:

```
[131] "W<U+008A>rmflasche <e3>Hug<d2>\r \r"                                             
[132] "Held f<U+009F>r einen Tag <d0> Aufblasbare Superhelden-Ausr<U+009F>stung \r"     
[133] "Metallic Tattoos & Haarkrone <d0> Fashion Set\r"
```

I tried to use `iconv` but I have no clue in which encoding the files was saved in the first place.

EDIT: I am adding the first lines of the csv file:

```
name;product_details
Geschenkset Cupcake Dekoration ;"Erh�ltlich in vier Varianten: Cupcake Geschenkset � Weihnachtsglitzer"
```

Comment: can you show the iconv line? and also part of what's inside csv file which has this kind of data

Comment: do you think that could be a problem of my machine? I just found out that when printing out put from a tibble I get weird characters as well, e.g. "A tibble: 325 <U+00D7> 2"

Comment: what's the encoding set in file -> reopen with encoding, set to utf-8 and try

Comment: paste some part of csv as well, it will be helpful

Comment: that didn't work; this line I got from the console: "A tibble: 325 <U+00D7> 2". Would it be the case that R as whole is using a different encoding? I am using a MacBook Pro 2016 with macOS Sierra

Comment: <U+00D7> is the unicode character encoding for multiplacation symbol http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm

Comment: yes, but do you have any idea why the console is displaying <U+00D7> instead of the multiplication symbol itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading your file like this

```
readLines("filepath", encoding="UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had the same problem described in this question [Set locale to system default UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577764/set-locale-to-system-default-utf-8). The most voted answered solved my problem as well.