# Input from keyboard does not return correct Unicode character

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I have values that contains the Unicode character U+0103 `ă` in a UTF-8 CSV file. This and other UTF-8 characters from the Vietnamese language display correctly in the dataframe.

```
ID     Subject
1      Ngữ văn
2      Toán
3      Địa lí
```

However, when I filter the dataframe, this works:

```
df %>% filter(Subject == "Toán")

# A tibble: 1 x 2
 ID   Subject
<dbl> <chr>  
  1   Toán
```

But not this:

```
df %>% filter(Subject == "Ngữ văn")

# A tibble: 0 x 2
# ... with 2 variables: ID <dbl>, Subject <chr>
```

I compared the character string `"Ngữ văn"` and and the string with the `ă` manually specified:

```
> "Ngữ văn"
[1] "Ngữ van"
> paste("Ngữ v","\u0103", "n", sep = "")
[1] "Ngữ văn"
> paste("Ngữ v","\u0103", "n", sep = "") == "Ngữ văn"
[1] FALSE
```

Why does inputting the letter `ă` returns `a` and how can I fix this?

My session info:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(Subject == "Ngữ văn" )
#  ID Subject
#1  1 Ngữ văn
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Subject = c("Ngữ văn", "Toán", "Địa lí"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I have already mentioned above: inputting `"Ngữ văn"` in the console gives you `"Ngữ van"`

Comment: @rendiku can you please check your sessionInfo

Comment: i added my sessionInfo above @akrun

Comment: @rendiku I have a different settings, probably that could be the reason `en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8`

Comment: @rendiku you may try from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577764/set-locale-to-system-default-utf-8) link

Comment: thanks! i put `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "vietnamese")` in .Rprofile and it worked!